# Vmware player installing firmware UEFI

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm trying to install a new VM with UEFI

I've tried this : https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/138399-vmware-create-efi-virtual-machine-solved.html

adding this line in the .vmx :

```
firmware = "efi"
```

But it keeps starting with BIOS.

Any idea ? (Is this the right place to ask ?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you also add the line `bios.forceSetupOnce = "TRUE"`?

Comment: Is it a 32-bit or 64-bit VM?